# discord.py repost images the user attached

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this code

```
  if message.content.startswith("add"):
    if len(message.attachments) == 0:
      await message.channel.send("There's no picture.")
    elif message.content == "add":
      await message.channel.send("There's no text.")
    else:
      text = str(message.attachments)[0]
      url = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', text) # extracts the url out of the string
      await message.channel.send(f"{message.content[4:]}")
      await message.channel.send(file=discord.File(str(url)))
```

For example, I send "add Abc" with an attachment of a picture of an airplane, it should just repost that airplane picture and also send Abc

But it doesn't for some reason, the thing returns

```
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

what are you doing there with the URL?
please read the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#attachment)

also please note that Discord sends Images as a Image if you just post the URL, so you could send the Message with the following line: `await message.channel.send(content=f'{message.content[4:]}\nmessage.attachments[0].url'`

Answer (score 0):

```
attached = await message.attachments[0].to_file()
await message.channel.send(file=attached)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) will help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.